# change character to date in R

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to change the type of a character vector to date.

The dates I'm working with look like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  Created_date_c = 
    c("01/10/2022", "21/11/2021", "15/08/2022", "01/01/2022")
)
```

However I am trying to change the type of `Created_date_c` to date so that I can filter the date by dat, like just to choose October for example.

I used this:

```r
df$Created_date_c <- as.Date(df$Created_date_c, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
```

But a lot of dates got lost.

The date should be full, without missing dates. For example, the range is from October to mid-November but after using `as.Date(df$Created_date_c, format = "%m-%d-%Y")`, it's only October and November goes away.

Comment: The `format` argument tells `as.Date` how it should expect strings to be formatted, so the format you provide needs to actually match the data. Yours doesn't: you tell it to look for "m-d-Y" but then give it "d/m/Y". Was there some way you expected this argument to work differently?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change your date format a little: '/' or '-' does matter.

```r
df$Created_date_c <- as.Date(df$Created_date_c, '%d/%m/%Y')
```